# How is convection possible in fluids, in the absence of a contact surface for any buoyant force?

Tags: ideal-gas, atmospheric-science, buoyancy

I don't understand why liquids and gases are acted upon by a buoyant force.

In a solid immersed on some fluid medium, the pressure pressure difference caused by gravity exerts a force on the surface of the object, which is different depending on height. This force imbalance causes a upward force proportional to the volume of the object and density of the fluid.

However, fluids lack a contact surface that can be pushed against. In gases, particularly, the molecules rarely even interact.

Yet, we see all those convection currents happening in the atmosphere.

How would the occasional collisions between the hot and cold gas particles generate, in large scale, the observed buoyant force on the hot air masses?

Comment: I don't think it's true to say that in a gas the molecules rarely interact.  The assumption of a gas being a continuous fluid requires the mean free path to be very small compared to the length scales of interest, i.e. the molecules move a very small distance, on average, between each collision.

Comment: For air at ambient pressure, the mean free path is ~70nm.